# updation of dirty pages in swap in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel, virtual-memory

What I have read,

1. Swap space has no file system
2. Disk has filesystem. Whenever a file which is on disk is modified then its modified content is written to new disk block (and not to the original block) and associated data structures are updated.
3. Dirty pages are written back to the Swap before they are paged out(due to various reasons).

The question is, are dirty pages written back to their original Page-Slots or they are written to new Page-Slot ? If written to new page slot then what is the procedure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to answer the questions you raise in generic terms.

First of all, the page partition is called a swap partition in eunuchs for historical reasons. In ye olde days before virtual memory, entire processes were swapped out. Now processes are paged out.

For performance reasons, the operating system wants to do paging in complete blocks. A page generally maps to one or more disk blocks. On most non-eunuchs systems, the page file is a contiguous file. Paging is done using virtual block I/O to the page file (and the executable file or libraries).

The traditional eunuchs file (inode) system was quick and dirty designed. There is no ability to create a contiguous file. The only way to write contiguous data is to use an entire disk or disk partition. Eunuchs databases and page files have then been disk partitions (Mac OS uses a different system). Instead of doing virtual block I/O to a page file the system does logical (or physical) I/O to the disk.

When a process allocates virtual memory, normally page file space is a prerequisite. Thus the page file location for a page frame remains in the same location. If there were not he case, a process might need to have a page out and not have an available location in the page file.

Comment: Actually I went through the Crowley from the begining and probably I didn't pay enough attention hence historical and new system got mixed up in my mind. Thanks for clearing it up.